# Postfix not sending, LibClamAV Error: mpool_malloc

Tags: postfix, clamav

This question is closely related this this [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/810739/clamav-error-mpool-malloc-attempt-to-allocate-8388608-bytes).  However, in this case, clamav is going crazy and filling up boot.log, writing to it every second (and getting huge).  Furthermore, postfix is totally dead.  Postfix doesn't even write to mail.log or mail.err.  Restarting both by:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-daemon restart
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam restart
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Doesn't seem to have any effect. Here is the output:

```
ubuntu@linode:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-daemon restart

/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon: line 354: kill: (-4308) - No such process
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon: line 365: kill: (-4308) - No such process
 * Stopping ClamAV daemon clamd                                          [ OK ]
/usr/sbin/clamd already running.
 * Starting ClamAV daemon clamd                                          [ OK ]
ubuntu@linode:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam restart
 * Starting ClamAV virus database updater freshclam                      [ OK ]
ubuntu@linode:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
 * Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                         [ OK ]
 * Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                         [ OK ]
```

This is on ubuntu.  This is client's server.  This started a few days ago (2016/10/23?)  They are not very technical and I don't think they made any specific changes.

I have been testing mail by:

```
echo "My message" | mail -s testing me@gmail.com
```

As mentioned, both var/log/mail.log and mail.err are both at 0 bytes

Just about at wit's end.  **How can I resolve this?**

Edit: Also tried to update by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libclamav-dev
```

No effect

Comment: I am experiencing the very same thing, boot.log filling up with clamav errors, and postfix/sendmail going down. Have you made any headway?

Comment: @David Allen While it might have been in combination with some other changes, ultimately, rebooting the entire server resolved the issue for me.